# Are mongo connection pools using the same thread pool?

Tags: mongodb

In my application I am setting up connection with 3 MongoDB clusters. I wonder whether those 3 connection pools are set up on single thread pool or driver prepares separate thread pool for each connection pool?

Comment: What are you connecting to the database with? E.g. Java driver, Node driver?

Comment: Mongo java driver